# How the (-) operator converting negative numbers to positive works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is an example:

```
def absolute(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x
    else:
        return -x

print(absolute(3))
print(absolute(-119))
```

The Output:

```
3
119
```

Now, how `-119` became a positive number by just using the (-) subtraction operator?

### Thanks.

Update:

For those who misunderstood my q,

So I'm repeat, How -119 turns to be 119 by using the (-) operator! as in `return -x` in the code above. Nope, I know it would be a multiplication but how it is achieved by using (-) operator?

Comment: thats just how it works. `print(---------------8)` prints -8.

Comment: The `-` prefix operator can be seen as a multiplication by -1. From there, it's basic math: `-1 x -119 = 119`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about basic mathematics, not programming.

Comment: Where is the multiplication operator here?

Comment: Why are you not equally wondering why `-` turns `119` into `-119`?

Comment: Update:

For those who misunderstood my q,

So I'm repeat, How -119 turns to be 119 by using the (-) operator! as in return -x in the code above. Nope, I know it's a multiplication but how it is achieved by using (-) operator?

Comment: What part of the negation operator do you not understand? As pointed out in an answer below, the `-` can have multiple roles: by itself in front of a variable or number (int, float), it becomes the negation operator, and the value is negated. For integers and floats, that means the sign is reversed. In standard math, this is exactly the same. A `3` turns into `-3`, and `-3` turns into `--3`, which is equivalent to (and normally written as) `3` (as two negatives multiplied result in a positive, or a double negation results in the original value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the binary operator `x - y` aka "x subtract y" with the unary operator `-x` aka "negate x". They are different things.

`-x` returns the negation of `x`. If `x` is positive, `-x` is negative, and vice versa.

Unary `-` is: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.neg

Binary `-` is: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub

Comment: Instead of the `operator` module, you may (also) want to refer to the table in the [numeric types section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) of the standard library documentation.